# TypeError: webpackManifestPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: webpack

My build script is failing after upgrading webpack with the following error:

> TypeError: webpackManifestPlugin is not a constructor

looking at my config file which is the source of this error, I could not figure out what is wrong - I do declare it before calling it:

```
const { webpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
.....
new webpackManifestPlugin({...})
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you imported the wrong named export from the package. The right one is `WebpackManifestPlugin` not `webpackManifestPlugin`

```js
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
```

Comment: Thanks!
maybe u can help me with another issue after the upgrade:
configMerge = require('webpack-merge')
module.exports = configMerge(commonConfig, {
                 ^

TypeError: configMerge is not a function

Comment: Using the named export function instead using a default one ` const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')`